# Overruling the colour scheme from ggplot2, to force black and white on code written with colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as follows, for which I run `ggplot` code:

```
data <- structure(list(country_mean_rep = structure(c(73.6995708154506, 
93.5501285347044, 85.1529051987768, 91.1017369727047, 79.5562130177515, 
84.6751054852321, 89.8, 86.8826405867971, 94.2247191011236, 70.2321428571429, 
88.4107142857143), label = "label", format.stata = "%9.2f"), 
    country_mean_crime = c(0.0944206008583691, 0.0565552699228792, 
    0.0336391437308868, 0.205955334987593, 0.130177514792899, 
    0.282700421940928, 0.220512820512821, 0.415647921760391, 
    0.387640449438202, 0.200892857142857, 0.292207792207792), 
    country_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 
    14L, 16L, 20L), .Label = c("Albania", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", 
    "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", 
    "Cambodia", "Chile", "CostaRica", "Croatia", "Czech", "Ecuador", 
    "Estonia", "FYROM", "Georgia", "Germany", "Greece", "Guyana", 
    "Hungary", "Ireland", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kyrgyzstan", 
    "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Malawi", "Mali", "Moldova", "Philippines", 
    "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Senegal", "Serbia&Montenegro", 
    "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", 
    "SriLanka", "Tajikistan", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "Uzbekistan", 
    "Vietnam"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

# On which I like to run the following code:

ggplot(data, aes(x=country_mean_rep, y=country_mean_crime)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="linear", fill="linear"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x, ) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="quadratic", fill="quadratic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="cubic", fill="cubic"), 
              method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(colour="Functional Form", fill="Functional Form")
```

[image]

I have tried everything to get this code in black and white. Removing `colour`, adding `theme_bw` everywhere, but I cannot get rid of the colours. Can anyone help?

Maybe more important, is there some way to "hard" overrule the colours scheme, so that I do not have to mess with the code and can still get black and white?

Comment: `+ scale_fill_grey() + scale_color_grey()`?

Comment: Thanks, I did not think it was that easy.. I think I will remove the question in that case.